# Use of retain in initWithCoder?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am reading up about Encoding and Decoding and I noticed that sometimes people miss the retain off the end, I have also noticed that retain is sometimes used on some varables but not others. Can I ask ...

**(1) What is the purpose of this retain and why is it sometimes not needed?**

**(2) Does the use of the retain imply that I need to match it with a release, and if so where?**

```
- (id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *) decoder {
    name  = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey: @"CardName"] retain];
    email = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey: @"CardEmail"] retain];
}
```

or

```
- (id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *) decoder {
    name  = [decoder decodeObjectForKey: @"CardName"];
    email = [decoder decodeObjectForKey: @"CardEmail"];
}
```

gary

Comment: Most likely, code samples you see that don't explicitly retain the decoded object are using setter methods to claim ownership.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your first snippit represents the correct behaviour. The `-decodeObjectForKey:` method does not contain the word `init`, `copy` or `new`, so there is no promise made about whether the object returned will stay around, and if so for how long. If your object needs its ivars to stay around, it should `-retain` the objects it gets back from the decoder. This `-retain` will need to be balanced with a `-release`, which will be in your object's `-dealloc` method (so the object is created with some initial ivars which it retains, and it releases its ivars when it is destroyed). Like this:

```
- (void)dealloc {
  [name release];
  [email release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

The retain/release dance is not needed:

- if you're using garbage collection
- if your object doesn't need to claim ownership of its ivars. That's not often the case; delegates usually aren't retained (but then usually aren't archived either), and properties declared with the `assign` modifier aren't either.

Comment: I probably need another trip round the memory management guide, can I ask, if I alloc a simple class that contains a single NSString instance variable should I be releasing that in my dealloc or will it get released when I release the containing instance?

Comment: yes, you should retain the instance variable when it gets set and release it when it's no longer needed. I've got a blog post with a set of links to memory management articles: http://iamleeg.blogspot.com/2008/12/cocoa-memory-management.html

Comment: Thank you Graham, I think I a getting there now, I have linked you blog post for future reference. Have a great weekend.

Answer (score 9):

You may also have been misled by people using properties as well.  Its possible that you've seen people doing:

```
- (id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *) decoder {
    self.name  = [decoder decodeObjectForKey: @"CardName"];
    self.email = [decoder decodeObjectForKey: @"CardEmail"];
}
```

which would be fine if name and email were defined as 'retain' properties.  Of course, you then get into the argument about whether its legal/advisable to use property accessors in initialise/dealloc methods - some say yes, some say no, Apple seem to be on the side of no but haven't ever really given a good reason that I can see.